# How to operate a variable of another class

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing a function of QTMovieView. I want to double click on the QTMovieView to make it exit full screen mode. The QTMovieView is control by AppController.m, and I write the exit fullscreenmode function in the AppController. Because I want to capture the event of double click the QTMovieView. So I have to override the mouseDown event. The Override function is write in the "QTMovieView+TFOverrideDrag.h"

QTMovieView+TFOverrideDrag.m

```
#import "QTMovieView+TFOverrideDrag.h"
#include "AppController.h"


@implementation QTMovieView (TFOverrideDrag)

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   [self.superview becomeFirstResponder];
    NSInteger clickCount = [theEvent clickCount];
    if (2 == clickCount) {
        [AppController exitFullScreen:self];

        NSLog(@"SS");
    }
    NSLog(@"MDown");
}
```

and this function override successfully. but the exitFullScreen function fail. how can I  fix it? Thanks

Update

AppController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>

@interface AppController : NSDocument
{
    QTMovie     *qtmovie;
    QTMovieView *_movieView;
}

@property (assign)  IBOutlet    QTMovieView *movieView;


- (IBAction)toggleFullscreen:(id)sender;
+(IBAction)exitFullScreen:(id)sender;

@end
```

AppController.m

```
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController
@synthesize movieView=_movieView;


- (IBAction)toggleFullscreen:(id)sender
{

    _movieView=_movieView;
    NSDictionary *fullScreenOptions = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber     numberWithBool:YES]forKey:NSFullScreenModeSetting] retain];

    [_movieView enterFullScreenMode:[[NSScreen mainScreen] retain] withOptions:fullScreenOptions];

}

+(void)exitFullScreen:(id)sender
{
    _movieView=_movieView;
    NSLog(@"exitFullscreen");

    NSDictionary *fullScreenOptions = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]forKey:NSFullScreenModeSetting] retain];
    [_movieView exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:fullScreenOptions];
}
@end
```

Comment: You will need to *subclass* `QTMovieView`, not provide the implementation via a category.

Comment: but how do I accomplish exitFullscreen?

Comment: Can you post your `exitFullScreen` code from both the .h and .m files?

Comment: ok I already post them both!

Comment: the problem is still there...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `AppController` declares a class method like `+(void)exitFullScreen:`? If not, then you will either need to change your instance method to a class method (use a `+` instead of a `-`) or subclass the `QTMovieView` class and pass an instance of `AppController` to the instance.

Comment: I'm sure I declare +exitFullScreen: in AppController. and I'm sorry I'm new to Object-C, how to subclass the QTMovieView class and pass an instance of AppController to the instance?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!!! I fixed the problem by this :

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   [self.superview becomeFirstResponder];
    NSInteger clickCount = [theEvent clickCount];
    if (2 == clickCount) {
        NSDictionary *fullScreenOptions = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber     numberWithBool:YES]forKey:NSFullScreenModeSetting] retain];
        [super enterFullScreenMode:[[NSScreen mainScreen] retain] withOptions:fullScreenOptions];
        NSLog(@"SS");
    }
    NSLog(@"MDown");
}
```

the key is "super".